# .toUpperCase() breaks the Add Customer button of a CRUD webapp with spring/hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to get the customers info to be display in upper case (only first letters for first and last name) in this web app. As first thing i tried to implement the jstl upper case function in the jsp file and it worked. But when I try to update the customer info, in the update form, those value get display as all lower case. This happens only if you add the customer info in lower case to begin with.

So what i did is add the .toUpperCase() method in my Customer class, in the Email getter as such:

```
public String getEmail() {
    email = email.toUpperCase();
    return email;
}
```

And indeed, this works, the email info get displayed in upper case.
But for some reason, this breaks the Add Customer button giving this error at runtime:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing [WEB-INF/view/customer-form.jsp] at line [48]

45:                     
46:                     <tr>
47:                         <td><label>Email:</label>
48:                         <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
49:                     </tr>
50:                     
51:                     <tr>

org.springframework.beans.InvalidPropertyException: Invalid property 'email' of bean class [com.luv2code.springdemo.entity.Customer]: Getter for property 'email' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

By removing the upper case method, the button returns to work properly.

Comment: Are you checking for nulls anywhere before this method?

Answer (score 0):

Well ok a simple check if(email != not null) will do the job, i don't know how i have got the idea or if i understood it properly, but seems to work fine now :/